# Storing the result of a function call as a variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, variables, call

What do you call it when you bind the result (return) of a function call, and not the function itself to a variable in JavaScript like this?

```
const arr = (function () {
      const anotherArr = []
      for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        anotherArr.push(i)
      }
      return anotherArr
    }())

console.log(arr)
```

The above code is just an example, so I am not trying to achieve anything or need suggestions on how to do things differently :) I just wonder what it is called.

Comment: It's called an Immediately Invoked Function Expression, or IIFE for short.
See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE for more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question's a bit ambiguous.  There is no binding per se.  You're just making an assignment from the function to the variable.

What you may be looking for is the name of this type of expression where the function executes immediately.

Immediately Invoked Function Expression.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE

If this is not what you are looking for - please clarify.